# How to reassign 'host' for the root user of a docker mysql instance

Tags: mysql, django, docker, docker-compose

I have two docker instances, one for the API and one for the DB of a project. I was able to run both without issues, but today I wasn't able to. The DB instance builds without issue, but the API is unable to communicate with it, due to the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1130, "Host '172.x.x.x' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server")
```

Some googling led me to check the host for the root user, which gives me:

```
SELECT host from mysql.user where User='root';
+-----------+
| host      |
+-----------+
| localhost |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Below is `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3336:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ***
      MYSQL_USER: ***
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ***
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ***
    restart: always
    command:
      [
        "mysqld",
        "--character-set-server=utf8mb4",
        "--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci",
      ]
  api:
    container_name: api
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: ./etc/docker/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
```

So, I have a few questions:

1. Any idea why the API instance's IP changed? I'm assuming it changed, since it was able to connect without issues since yesterday.
2. Is there a way to solve this issue via docker-compose/Makefile? I was able to ssh into the DB instance and change the host manually, but this is obviously not sustainable.
3. Is there any way to change the IP of the API instance to `localhost`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the IP of your IP container has changed and that is why you cannot connect, verify that first.

You can add a user that can connect from any ip to your databases.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I would have to manually create this user every time I build the containers. This isn't very useful to me, but if there is a way to automate this, it would certainly be helpful.

Comment: This user will be created automatically, in the definition of your container you should do it.